# SweetAlert2 10 is showing big font contents on bootstrap

Tags: sweetalert2

I'm trying to upgrade from sweetAlert 8 to 10 and after install I'm geting font swal-content very big (maybe 3 or 5 times)
[image]

You can see here the original size
[image]

I tried with .all.min.js and also css and css alone.

Thanks!